# Why Midoriya didnt get another Full Gauntlet after the one he destroyed?

Tags: my-hero-academia

We've seen Midoriya after the events of My Hero Academia: 2 heroes. Another Full Gauntlet would have been very useful for him, but he never got one. Why Midoriya didnt get another Full Gauntlet after the one he destroyed?

Answer (score 1):

Because the movies are NOT CANON. The gauntlets are so the movie can have deku use One-for-all at 100 percent.

Answer (score 0):

Because he needed to learn how to master one for all normally without help of devices that would protect his body from the repercussions. It just wouldn't be right if he used that kind of support. And what if it breaks during battle, then he would be screwed.

Story-wise though, Melissa probably spent years developing and producing Full Gauntlet. It would take a while to reproduce a new one for Midoriya.